# How to sort column in mysql having date in format of %m/%d/%Y?

Tags: mysql, sorting, date, columnsorting

I want to sort a date-of-birth column in a table which has date stored in format of %m/%d/%Y . When I use order by , the column values are being treated and sorted as string and not date. I have tried UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function but it also seems to be not working. What are the possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [STR_TO_DATE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DueDate,'%m/%d/%Y ') DESC
```